# How can I plot this Hurwitz Zeta-based function at negative arguments?

Tags: plotting, special-functions

Here is the code:

```
pw[y_, x_] := -HurwitzZeta[1 - x, 1/2 + y] x
Plot3D[pw[b, p], {b, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, Mesh -> {6, 5}, 
 ClippingStyle -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[.8], Specularity[White, 20]], 
 PlotPoints -> 100, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

How can I plot this function at $b<-1$? Numerically it evaluates well.

Comment: I get a nice plot with `PlotPoints -> Automatic` Imo it's not a good idea to use ` ClippingStyle -> None` here

Comment: @eldo I used the both of your pieces of advice, added PlotPoints -> Automatic and removed ClippingStyle -> None and still it cannot plot anything at b<-1

Comment: b must be >= 0. With negative b-values there are branch cuts and singularities (see doc). You can plot f.e `Plot3D[pw[b, p], {b, 0, 3}, {p, -6, 6}]`

Comment: @eldo numerically it evaluates well.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Try `Table[pw[b, p], {b, -3, 3, 1.}, {p, -3, 3, 1.}]`. Error messages and indeterminate values!

Comment: @eldo try pw[-3, -3], pw[-3, 2], pw[-3, 1]. They all produce good results.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear@pw

pw[x_, y_] := -HurwitzZeta[1 - y, 1/2 + x] y
```

With negative x-values you get many complex numbers and indeterminate values. For example:

```
pw[-3., -2.5] // N
```

> 29.052 + 28.9903 I

```
pw[-3., 0.] // N
```

> Indeterminate

Avoiding negative x-values gives the following plot

```
Plot3D[pw[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

If you want to plot negative x-values you must skip the `0` by choosing a plot range of f.e. `{-3.01, 3.01}` and you can convert the complex numbers with `Abs`

```
Plot3D[Abs @ pw[b, p], {b, -3.01, 3.01}, {p, -3.01, 3.01}]
```

[image]

From the documentation:

> Unlike Zeta, HurwitzZeta  has singularities at a==-n for non-negative
>   integers n ...  HurwitzZeta has branch cut discontinuities in the
>   complex a plane running from 0 to -Infinity.